# Knockout fires update event only once

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this setup

```
<div id="mealModal" class="modal fade" data-bind="with: jsonData,selectPicker" data-ajax-form-ko="true">
```

But when jsonData changes, the update event of knockout binding selectPicker is not fired.

Comment: Show your model and the code for the `selectPicker` binding-handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of KOv3, bindings are refreshed independently ([source](http://knockoutjs.com/upgrade-notes/v3.0.0.html#bindings-are-now-refreshed-independently)).  So it's possible you're expecting the old behavior but aren't aware that it changed.

But, what you have here is two separate bindings, a `with` binding that depends on `jsonData` and a `selectPicker` binding with no dependencies.  So, (with the caveat of not knowing the implementation of `selectPicker`), I wouldn't expect the `selectPicker` to update more than once, since it has no dependencies.